# Is there a way to make a box reflective in vpython?

Tags: python, vpython

I need to find a way to make a box in Vpython reflect everything around it. Is there an attribute in vpython's box class to make it reflective?

I've tried `box.shinniness` because I saw that that was an attribute. No luck.

```
by_mirror = box(pos=vector(0, 0, 0), shinniness=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the shininess only affects the "spotlight" aspects of the lights. There isn't a way to make a mirror.